# Natural Join between two group by queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join

another little problem here.
I have to merge two different table.
In the first one, i have to find the average external temperature in a hour datetime range.
In the second one instead, i have to calculate the Kilowatt per hour use, in a hour datetime range.
The single queries works perfectly, but when i try to join them, they doesn't work.
This query doesn't work:

```
select dataora, AVG(Test) 
from temperature 
where dataora between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31' GROUP BY date(dataora),hour(dataora)
natural join (
    SELECT
      (t1.dt) AS time,(case
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value>0
          then abs(t1.value - t2.value)
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value=0
          then t2.value
          else t1.value END)kwhg, 
     (case
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1>0
          then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1=0
          then t2.value1
     when t1.value1=t2.value1 AND t1.value1>0 
        then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
      else 0 END) kwhc, 
      (case
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2>0
          then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2=0
          then t2.value2
     when t1.value2=t2.value2 AND t1.value2>0 
        then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
      else 0 END)kwhi,
    (case
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3>0
          then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3=0
          then t2.value3
     when t1.value3=t2.value3 AND t1.value3>0 
        then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
      else 0 END) kwhfm
    FROM 
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t1
        JOIN
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t2
        on t1.dt = t2.dt + interval 1 hour) t3
```

This one get me only 1 row (the first one, instead of the 720 needed in this example):

```
    SELECT
      (t1.dt) AS time,(case
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value>0
          then abs(t1.value - t2.value)
     when t1.value>t2.value AND t2.value=0
          then t2.value
          else t1.value END)kwhg, 
     (case
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1>0
          then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
     when t1.value1>t2.value1 AND t2.value1=0
          then t2.value1
     when t1.value1=t2.value1 AND t1.value1>0 
        then abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1)
      else 0 END) kwhc, 
      (case
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2>0
          then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
     when t1.value2>t2.value2 AND t2.value2=0
          then t2.value2
     when t1.value2=t2.value2 AND t1.value2>0 
        then abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2)
      else 0 END)kwhi,
    (case
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3>0
          then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
     when t1.value3>t2.value3 AND t2.value3=0
          then t2.value3
     when t1.value3=t2.value3 AND t1.value3>0 
        then abs(t1.value3 - t2.value3)
      else 0 END) kwhfm, AVG(Test)
    FROM 
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t1
        JOIN
        (SELECT (dataora) dt, MAX(kwhg) value, MAX(kwhc) value1, MAX(kwhi) value2, MAX(kwhfm) value3  FROM misure where dataora between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-31' GROUP BY date(dt),hour(dt)) t2
        on t1.dt = t2.dt + interval 1 hour
natural join temperature
```

I use the natural join because i need the real kilowatt per hour and the average of a 4 measures(every 15 minutes) of external temperature for every hour.
Maybe the answer is easy, but i haven't find it!
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `natural join`.  It joins on all the fields that have the same name.  Instead, do a normal join (I would guess either `inner join` or `left outer join`) and use an `on` clause on the date:

```
(<subquery 1>) s1 join
(<subquery 2>) s2
on s1.time = s2.time
```